# Create a new list out of elements at specific indices in an existing list

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I have a list and want to create a new list out of it, but only out of elements at specific indices.

For example:

```
// Form a new list made of people at indices 1, 3, 5, 44.
List<People> newList = existingList.ElementsAt(1,3,5,44);
```

I would hate to reinvent the wheel on this one, is there some built-in way?

Comment: Are indices known to you at compile time or are dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var newList = new List<People>
{
  existingList[1],
  existingList[3],
  existingList[5],
  existingList[44]
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
HashSet<int> indexes = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 3, 5, 44 };
List<People> newList = existingList.Where(x => indexes.Contains(existingList.IndexOf(x))).ToList();
```

Or use a plain old `for` loop:

```
HashSet<int> indexes = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 3, 5, 44 };
List<int> newList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < existingList.Count; ++i)
    if (indexes.Contains(i))
        newList.Add(existingList[i]);
```

Comment: Originally I thought of this but wouldn't it be a bit much to loop through the list when OP knows what elements to extract?

Comment: It depends on whether the indexes are known at compile time or if they are dynamic.

Comment: Known at compile time. I am using this for unit testing, argument matching.